# How to upload Large files using node.js and spsave module

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript, nodejs, custom-javascript

I have implemented multiple file uploads using `spsave`. But whenever i try to upload larger file(5mb+) files are not getting uploaded.

```
const apiRequest = spsave(coreOptions, creds, fileOptions);
promiseArray.push(apiRequest);
Promise.all(promiseArray)
          .then((data) => {
            res.status(201).json({
              success: true,
              message: uploadSuccess,
            });
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            res.status(500).json({
              success: false,
              message: err.message,
            });
          });
```

and returning `ns_error_connection_refused` error.

Comment: I am checking to see how things are going there on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to it is use of `connect-busboy` and `fs` modules and save files in file system rather than buffering it and eventually read the file and upload to sharepoint, later remove file from file system.